# how to adding the source project into a project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Having a android project which has three modules A, B and C

in C module's build.gradle it has dependency:

```
implementation("com.dev.base:lib_X:$versions.xxx)
```

I have the lib_X source on the machine and would like to include the lib_X's source code in this project,  so in the module C's settings.grdale added:

```
include ':lib_X'
project(':lib_X').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../lib_X_proj/lib_X/')
```

and in the C module's build.gradle change the dependency:

```
implementation(":lib_X")
```

but got error says `:lib_X cannot be found`.  What would be wround?  The lib_X's relative code path is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the problem,

the

```
include ':lib_X'
project(':lib_X').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../lib_X_proj/lib_X/')
```

should be put in the top project's settings.grdale instead of the C module's.